# Dockerfile - gradlew stuck on downloading

Tags: docker, port, virtual-machine

I am building a Docker-image from Dockerfile using this command:

```
docker build -it /root/Documents/myDockerfiles/tomcat/.
```

The Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
[root@srv01 ~]# cat /root/Documents/myDockerfiles/tomcat/Dockerfile
FROM tomcat:8.0.32-jre8
MAINTAINER "John Doe <johndoe@dough.com>"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://myusername:mypassword@mygiturl/mygroup/myproject.git
RUN cd ./myproject/ && ./gradlew war
```

So it basically clones an existing git-repo, cds into the cloned directory, and runs the gradle wrapper.

Problem is that the gradle-wrapper seems to get no connection to the outside, because:

```
Step 5 : RUN cd ./myproject && ./gradlew war 
---> Running in d01b57b9f932 Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip 
(here its stuck, gradlw can't communicate to the outside)
```

I think it must be a ***firewall and port issue***, because when I do the same from my **local laptop** its not stuck, but executing it on my **VM on some Extranet-Cloud-Service** (whose name I can't mention) it stops right there.

So my questions are:

**1.) Why is it stuck there?

2.) What can I do to prevent it from being stuck there?**